# How to popup php(mixed with html tags) file in javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i want to popup full php file in javascript function...

i have javascript function like this...

```
    (function() {  
tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.wpc', {  
    init : function(ed, url) { 
        ed.addButton('wpc', {  
            title : 'Add Contact Us form',  
            image : url+'/dd_note.gif', 
            onclick : function() { 
               ** here i want to popup php(mixed with html tags) file**
            }  
        });  
    },  
    createControl : function(n, cm) {  
        return null;  
    },  
});  
tinymce.PluginManager.add('wpc', tinymce.plugins.wpc);  
})();
```

can anybody suggest me how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try using  `window.open(url);` ?

Comment: @MehmetSeçkin it's opening in another window that i don't want.. i want to pop it

Comment: I see, you might want to try jQueryUI's [.dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)() or some other pop-up plugins.

Comment: I think their are lot of plugins as other suggested, You just need to pick one.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the dialog extension from jQueryUI.

```
(function () {
    tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.wpc', {
        init: function (ed, url) {
            ed.addButton('wpc', {
                title: 'Add Contact Us form',
                image: url + '/dd_note.gif',
                onclick: function () {
                    $(document.body).append('<div id="myPopUpBox"></div>');
                    $("#myPopUpBox").dialog({
                        open: function (event, ui) {
                            $('#myPopUpBox').load('my.PHP.file.php');
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        },
        createControl: function (n, cm) {
            return null;
        },
    });
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('wpc', tinymce.plugins.wpc);
})();
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) (developed by Twitter).

You can then use their Modal system.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery popup plugins like color-box. just add its function code into onclick section of your function. You can download and read documentation for color-box from here:

http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code can help you.
// leanModal v1.1 by Ray Stone - http://finelysliced.com.au
// Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL

> (function($) {
>
> $.fn.extend({leanModal: function(options) {
>
> ```
>    var defaults = {top: 100, overlay: 0.5, closeButton: null};
>
>        var overlay = $("<div id='lean_overlay'></div>");
>
>        $("body").append(overlay);
>
>        options = $.extend(defaults, options);
>
>        return this.each(function() {
>
>            var o = options;
>
>            $(this).click(function(e) {
>
>                var modal_id = $(this).attr("href");
>
>                $("#lean_overlay").click(function() {
>
>                    close_modal(modal_id)
>
>                });>
>
>
>                $(o.closeButton).click(function() {
>
>                    close_modal(modal_id)
>
>                });
>
>                var modal_height = $(modal_id).outerHeight();
>
>                var modal_width = $(modal_id).outerWidth();
>
>                $("#lean_overlay").css({"display": "block", opacity: 0});
>
>      $("#lean_overlay").fadeTo(200, o.overlay);
>
>                $(modal_id).css({"display": "block", "position": "fixed", "opacity": 0, "z-index": 11000, "left": 50 + "%", "margin-left": -(modal_width / 2) + "px", "top": o.top + "px"});
>
>                $(modal_id).fadeTo(200, 1);
>
>                e.preventDefault()
>
>           })
>
>        });
>
>        function close_modal(modal_id)
>
>           {
>
>            $("#lean_overlay").fadeOut(200);
>
>            $(modal_id).css({"display": "none"})
>
>        }
>
>      }
> ```
>
> })
>
> })(jQuery);